# Modify Eclipse - SVN Repository perspective Find/Check Out As

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, tortoisesvn

I want to change the actions taken by Eclipse when the user right clicks a folder in the SVN Repository Exploring perspective.  Currently, because of our setup, users have to select "Find/Check Out As..." when they want to check out an SVN folder to their workspace.  Then they select the same choices for the next 4 boxes.  I want to change this to do the same functions behind the scenes and speed up that process - when they want to check out a folder, everything is done for them.